# PHP conditions and echoing HTML

Tags: php

When I'm using PHP and HTML I normally do it this way:

```
<?php if ($myvar = 'blah') {
   echo '<div>some html here</div>';
} else {
   echo 'Nothing here';
}
?>
```

This works but I now have a bunch of html and I need to add a condition and I am trying to avoid having to do this:

```
<?php if ($myvar = 'blah') {
   echo '<div>some html here</div>';
   echo '<div>some other html here</div>';
   echo '<div>some other html here</div>';
}
?>
```

Is there a way to wrapper the whole of the html block instead?

Comment: You probably want an equality test instead of an assignment inside that if statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the HTML block and reverse it.

```
<?php

// get value of $myvar here

?>

<?php if ($myvar == 'blah):?>

<div>some html here</div>
<div>some html here</div>

<?php elseif ($myvar == 'test'):?>

<div>some html here</div>
<div>some html here</div>
<div>some html here</div>

<?php else:?>

<div>some html here</div>

<?php endif;?>
```

Or you can also use EOD e.g.

```
echo <<<EOD

<div>some html here</div>
<div>some html here</div>
<div>some html here</div>

EOD;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just drop out of PHP mode.

```
<?php if ($myvar = 'blah') { ?>
   <div>some html here</div>
   <div>some other html here</div>
   <div>some other html here</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Or, if it makes sense to maintain it separately, move the data to another file:

```
<?php if ($myvar = 'blah') { 
    include('foo.php'); 
} ?>
```

Or, use [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
if ($myvar = 'blah') {
echo <<<EOT
<div>some html here</div>
<div>some other html here</div>
<div>some other html here</div>
EOT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead. The echo can span multiple lines

```
<?php if ($myvar = 'blah') {
   echo '<div>some html here</div>
   <div>some other html here</div>
   <div>some other html here</div>';
}
?>
```

Or you could use the multiple parameters of the echo function

```
<?php if ($myvar = 'blah') {
   echo '<div>some html here</div>',
   '<div>some other html here</div>',
   '<div>some other html here</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes do it this way:

```
<?php    
if ($myvar = 'blah') {
?>
   <div>some html here</div>
   <div>some other html here</div>
   <div>some other html here</div>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this?

**original**

```
echo '<div>some html here</div>';
echo '<div>some other html here</div>';
echo '<div>some other html here</div>';
```

**combine into one variable**

```
$html = '<div>some html here</div><div>some other html here</div><div>some other html here</div>'

echo $html;
```

**variable concatenation**

```
$html = '<div>some html here</div>';
$html .= '<div>some other html here</div>';
$html .= '<div>some other html here</div>';

echo $html;
```

**close php tags**

```
?>
<div>some html here</div>
<div>some other html here</div>
<div>some other html here</div>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

The **only** reliable way to **output** HTML is to drop out of PHP mode:

```
<?php if ($myvar = 'blah') { ?>
   <div>some html here</div>
   <div>some other html here</div>
   <div>some other html here</div>
<?php } ?>
```

No HTML tag should be printed out other than this way.

To store resulting HTML in a variable you can either use above method in conjuncion with output buffering, or use a heredoc/concatenation.